# How to identify decodable model issue for parsing?

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

With a root struct BTCMarketResponse there are two structs to decode according to the json data, "status" and "data". Upon decoding the Status model works correctly, however accessing decodedData.btcData returns nil. How can I identify the issue with the model ?

```
struct BTCMarketResponse: Codable{
    var status: Status?
    var btcData: BTCData?
    
    enum BTCMarketResponseKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case status = "status"
        case btcData = "data"
    }
    
    struct Status: Codable{
        var elapsed: Int?
        var timestamp: Date?
        
        enum StatusKeys: String, CodingKey{
            case elapsed = "elapsed"
            case timestamp = "timestamp"
        }
    }
    
    struct BTCData: Codable{
        let id: String?
        let symbol: String?
        let name: String?
        let slug: String?
        let contractAddresses: String?
        let internalTempAgoraId: String?
        let isVerified: Bool?
        let tagline: String?
        let overview: String?
        let background: String?
        let technology: String?
        let category: String?
        let sector: String?
        let tag: String?
        let sFarScore: Int?
        let tokenDistribution: TokenDistribution?
        let tokenDetails: TokenDetails?
        let organizations: [Organization]?
        let people: People?
        let relevantResources: [RelevantResource]?
        let consesusAlgorithm: String?
```

where the response for accessing the status object as print(decodedData.status!) is `Status(elapsed: Optional(2), timestamp: Optional(2021-12-25 18:31:34 +0000))` but print(decodedData.btcData) returns nil, so I am assuming there is an issue in the btcData model. I set all variables for all nested structs optional. JSON data to be accessed can be found by the link https://data.messari.io/api/v1/assets/bitcoin/profile

Comment: Tried with this model and it's working fine. https://gist.github.com/apple-avadhesh/44f2ec3c092b8d38c7230edfd4235640

Comment: Well the JSON decoding error is "`error: expected hexadecimal code in braces after unicode escape`", which I presume means the `\u003` characters for example aren't in the correct format for Swift.

Comment: Declare all properties non-optional (remove the question marks), wrap the `JSONDecoder` line in a `do catch` block and `print(error)` in the catch scope. the error tells you exactly what's wrong. Declaring everything carelessly as optional is a very bad practice and makes debugging pretty hard.